# Proving a function is bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Here's my question, and a suggestion for a solution. Please let me know if I'm wrong.

> Prove that the function $$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}$$ is bounded in $(0,\infty)$

Solution:
Using L'Hospital rule: $$\lim_{x\to0^+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=\frac{"0"}{"0"}$$=$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(\ln(x+1))'}{x'}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x+1}=1.$$

Now I proved that the function has a limit. I want to move the **Heine's definition**.

Can I say that since $f(x)\to1$ then $f(X_n)\to1$? If so, then from the theorem saying that "Every converges sequence is bounded" we can say that the function is bounded as well?

**Can I use Heine definition here at all?**
Thanks.

Comment: , What is $X_n$?

Comment: The idea will work, though it requires some effort.  Note that L'Hospital's Rule actually shows the limit is $0$, not $1$.

Comment: limit is missing

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm not quite sure about heine's idea, but  I'd like to be. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Not for a while, I will be away. By then there may be a full exploration.

Comment: @AndréNicolas thank you anyway :)

Comment: copper.hat has given a solution that I think is very much in the spirit of what you were looking for.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I meant to write that my answer was just elaborating your comment, but I wasn't sure what 'Heine's definition' meant so I held off...

Comment: What you wrote (better than I would have) is the reasonable interpretation of OP's request.  My comment was too elliptical for attribution.

Comment: @AndréNicolas here is the definition I meant in the post: http://www.math24.net/definition-of-limit-of-function.html the Heine definition states that a function f (x) has a limit L at x = a, if for every sequence $f(x_n)$, which has a limit at a, the sequence $f(x_n)$ has a limit L.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is trivially positive on $\mathbb{R}^+$, and the (convexity) inequality $e^y\geq 1+y$ implies $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for any $x>0$, hence your function is always between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:-**

Notice that $e^x\ge x+1$ for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is  just an elaboration of (my interpretation of) André's comment:

If $f:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, and $L_0=\lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x)$ and $L_\infty=\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist (and are finite), then $f$ is bounded.

To see this, note that there is some $\delta>0$ such that
if $x < \delta$, then $|f(x)| \le L_0 +1$, and similarly there is some
some $N$ such that if $x>N$, then $|f(x)| \le L_\infty +1$.

Since $f$ is continuous, it is bounded on the compact set $[\delta,N]$, hence
bounded everywhere.

It is straightforward to show $L_0 = 1, L_\infty = 0$ for the function given in the question.